# yylval undefined with lex and yacc

Tags: abstract-syntax-tree, yacc, lex

I was trying a simple program to create an abstract syntax tree using lex and yacc.

My yacc_file.y is

```
%{

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

  typedef struct node
  {
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
    char *token;
  } node;

  node *mknode(node *left, node *right, char *token);
  void printtree(node *tree);

#define YYSTYPE struct node *

%}

%start lines

%token  NUMBER
%token  PLUS    MINUS   TIMES
%token  LEFT_PARENTHESIS    RIGHT_PARENTHESIS
%token  END

%left   PLUS    MINUS
%left   TIMES

%%

lines:  /* empty */
        | lines line /* do nothing */

line:   exp END     { printtree($1); printf("\n");}
    ;

exp    : term             {$$ = $1;}
        | exp PLUS term     {$$ = mknode($1, $3, "+");}
        | exp MINUS term    {$$ = mknode($1, $3, "-");}
        ;

term   : factor           {$$ = $1;}
        | term TIMES factor  {$$ = mknode($1, $3, "*");}
        ;

factor : NUMBER           {$$ = mknode(0,0,(char *)yylval);}
        | LEFT_PARENTHESIS exp RIGHT_PARENTHESIS {$$ = $2;}
        ;
%%

int main (void) {return yyparse ( );}

node *mknode(node *left, node *right, char *token)
{
  /* malloc the node */
  node *newnode = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
  char *newstr = (char *)malloc(strlen(token)+1);
  strcpy(newstr, token);
  newnode->left = left;
  newnode->right = right;
  newnode->token = newstr;
  return(newnode);
}

void printtree(node *tree)
{
  int i;


  if (tree->left || tree->right)
    printf("(");

  printf(" %s ", tree->token);

  if (tree->left)
    printtree(tree->left);
  if (tree->right)
    printtree(tree->right);

  if (tree->left || tree->right)
    printf(")");
}

int yyerror (char *s) {fprintf (stderr, "%s\n", s);}
```

My lex_file.l file is

```
%{
#include "yacc_file.tab.h"
%}


%%

[0-9]+                {yylval = (int)yytext; return NUMBER;} 
                       /* cast pointer to int for compiler warning */
[ \t\n]               ;
"+"      return(PLUS);
"-"      return(MINUS);
"*"      return(TIMES);
"("      return(LEFT_PARENTHESIS);
")"      return(RIGHT_PARENTHESIS);
";"      return(END);


%%

int yywrap (void) {return 1;}
```

To run, I have done the following

```
yacc -d yacc_file.y
lex lex_file.y
cc y.tab.c lex.yy.c -o a.exe
```

I got the following error

```
lexfile.l: In function 'yylex':
lex_file.l:10:2: error: 'yylval' undeclared(first used in this function)
[0-9]+                  {yylval=(int)yytext; return NUMBER;}
```

I have searched on google and %union seems to solve the problem. But I am not sure how to use it.

Comment: Is the quotation mark on the second line of your "yacc" file a copy and paste error, or is it really in the file. If it is in the file, there are probably other compile-time errors. (And your link is probably blocked off-campus; at least, I see no code.)

Comment: copy paste error. Yeah I did not check the link. The code is the same though.

Comment: How are you compiling your flex and bison input, then?

Comment: I did not understand your question. What input?

Comment: Yeah. I am doing `cc y.tab.c lex.yy.c -o a.exe` to get the executable.

Comment: OK, that's your problem. I edited the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command

```
yacc -d yacc_file.y
```

produces a header file called `y.tab.h` and a C file called `y.tab.c`. That's the yacc-compatible default naming, and it does not agree with your flex file, which is expecting the header to be called `yacc_file.tab.h`.

You could just change the `#include` statement in your flex file, but that wouldn't be compatible with the build system at your college. So I suggest you change to the command `bison -d yacc_file.y` instead of your `yacc` command. That will produce a header file called `yacc_file.tab.h` and a C file called `yacc_file.tab.c`. (Of course, you will then have to change the `cc` command to compile `yacc_file.tab.c` instead of `y.tab.c`.)

Presumably there is some incorrect `yacc_file.tab.h` on your machine, which doesn't include a declaration of `yylval`. Hence the compilation error.

To avoid confusing yourself further, when you fix your build procedure I'd recommend deleting all the intermediate files -- `y.tab.h` and `y.tab.c` as well as `yacc_file.tab.c` and `yacc_file.tab.h`, and `lex.yy.c`. Then you can do a clean build without having to worry about picking up some outdated intermediate file.

---

Also, in `yacc_file.y`, you `#define` `YYSTYPE` as `struct node *`. That's fine, but the `#define` will not be copied into the generated header file; in the header file, `YYSTYPE` will be `#define`d as `int` if there is no other `#define` before the header file is `#include`d.

Moreover, in `lex_file.l` you use `yylval` as though it were an `int` (`yylval = (int)yytext;`) but I think that statement does not do what you think it does. What it does is reinterpret the *address* of `yytext` as an integer. That's legal but meaningless. What you wanted to do, I think, is to convert the string in `yytext` as an integer. To do that, you need to use `strtod` or some similar function from the standard C library.

Regardless, it is vital that the scanner and the parser agree on the type of `yylval`. Otherwise, things will go desperately wrong.

As you mention, it is possible to use a `%union` declaration to declare `YYSTYPE` as a union type. You should make sure you understand C union types, and also read the [bison manual section on semantics.](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Semantics).

Comment: A better answer would have been to simply point to correcting the #include

Comment: @ThomasDickey: OK, I edited the answer to make it clearer that changing the include statement is a possible fix, and why I think it might not be the best.

Comment: The behavior  in bison is not "new", but also rather old, and referring to standard behavior as old-fashioned is a problem with the answer.

Comment: @thomas: Ok, removed the word in question. I don't see any use of the word "new" in my answer.

Comment: @ThomasDickey: By the way, the "standard" (Posix) describes the fixed intermediate filenames as "a known deficiency in historical implementations", which could be seen as somewhat less polite than my abbreviated description. :) (fifth paragraph in http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/yacc.html#tag_20_159_18)

Comment: The current answer is improved.  If I had answered it, I might have pointed out that some `bison` packagers make a symbolic link to `yacc` (rather than provide a shell script with the `-y` option), which likely is the source of OP's confusion.  Also, it is likely that on a home-machine, OP is using byacc, which also provides renamed files -- likewise implemented quite a while ago.